# Should a 1-year gap in employment/education 12 years ago be mentioned in the ATAS application? If yes, where should it be mentioned?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, working-visas, uk-visa, certification

I am applying for an Academic Technology Approval Scheme (ATAS) certificate in order to start my job as an Assistant Professor at a Russell Group university in the UK. And I would like to know if a 1-year gap in employment/education history from 12 years ago should be mentioned in the ATAS application. The details of the gap are as follows:

After my undergraduate education, I started working in the industry. After a couple of years, I quit that job in order to study for the entrance examination for a master's degree education. This resulted in a one-year gap (from 2011 to 2012) before I started my master’s education. Should this gap be mentioned in the ATAS application? If yes, where should it be mentioned? Thank you.